# Shine PDF generate blank when load generate shine pdf template on ajax

Tags: shine-pdf

When We have Load shine pdf Generate page by ajax load that time pdf generate but it blank, but without ajax it worked fine.

We need to generate pdf in Background process so that call template on ajax.

let me know if you have any idea.

Thanks,
Piyush

Comment: what code you use in your ajax template? what url u use in ajax request?

Comment: ajax working fine now have some segment problem but let me know if you have any idea for pass value in ajax and that value get in to {embed="template/shinepdfgenerate" pdfcontent="Here"} from previous page. e.g total value get in "Here"